# using codeigniter and javascript pass encrypted parameters from view to controllers Error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, encryption

I'm trying to build a login form using codeigniter and jquery, what i was trying to do when client submit the form is the jquery change the `window.location` calling the validation function in the `controllers` passing both the `username` and `password` parameters **ENCRYPTED**

Here is my code

```
window.location.href = "/resturant/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/checklogin/" +
<?php $this->load->library('encrypt');
echo $this->encrypt->encode("$('#username').val()"); ?> +
"/" + $("#password").val();
```

This code doesn't work.

My question is, is this is how we encrypt parameters and pass them through the url?

**UPDATE**

The following code works fine thought:

```
window.location.href = "/resturant/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/checklogin/" +
<?php echo "$('#username').val()"; ?> + "/" + $("#password").val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing PHP and JavaScript in a way that is completely impossible. PHP is executed *on the server*, content is sent to the browser, and then, a *long* time later, JavaScript is run on the client's machine. The two cannot interact in this way. For PHP and JavaScript to interact at all, data has to be sent between the client and server via HTTP requests.

In the larger-scheme of things, you can't use server-side encryption in PHP to encrypt something client-side in JavaScript. You need to use SSL if you have any hope at all of securely communicating something to the server from JavaScript.

If you're simply trying to keep the username/password out of the URL, you should be using `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests. You should be doing this anyways for loggin in users.

**RE: Your update**

The problem is that, *purely by accident*, your second example outputs valid JavaScript which *happens* to give you the desired result.

That is, in your second example:

```
window.location.href = "/resturant/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/checklogin/" +
<?php echo "$('#username').val()"; ?> + "/" + $("#password").val();
```

The PHP `echo` is outputting a static string containing `"$('#username').val()"`, *not* the value in the `#username` field which *doesn't exist yet*, because we're in PHP and there isn't even a browser involved at this point. The output from PHP will look like this, which coincidentally happens to work correctly:

```
window.location.href = "/resturant/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/checklogin/" +
$('#username').val() + "/" + $("#password").val();
```

However, your first example is completely broken. This line:

```
echo $this->encrypt->encode("$('#username').val()");
```

is outputting the encrypted form of the literal string `"$('#username').val()"`; the result is going to be garbage and JavaScript parse errors.

You *cannot mix* PHP and JavaScript like this.

Comment: why the following line of code works then : `window.location.href = "/checklogin/" + <?php echo "$('#username').val()" ; ?>` isn't this mixing php and javascript ? Thanks for answering

Comment: It *doesn't work*, at least not in the way you think it does. It's literally resulting in this line of code: `window.location.href = "/checklogin/" + $('#username').val()`. The `<?php` tags aren't doing anything in this case but outputting the unexecuted JavaScript.